# How to cache React application in service worker

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm trying to create a React PWA from scratch. So far my project outputs the minified files to a `dist/js` folder.

In my service worker file I'm using Workbox to precache the app. This is my setting so far:

```
importScripts("./node_modules/workbox-sw/build/workbox-sw.js");

const staticAssets = [
    "./",
    "./images/favicon.png",
]

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(staticAssets);
```

Currently if I enable `offline` from dev tools > Service Workers, it throws these errors and the app fails to load:

```
3localhost/:18 GET http://localhost:8080/js/app.min.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:8080/manifest.json net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
3:8080/manifest.json:1 GET http://localhost:8080/manifest.json net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
logger.mjs:44 workbox Precaching 0 files. 2 files are already cached.
5:8080/manifest.json:1 GET http://localhost:8080/manifest.json net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could probably check this documentation using [PWA in React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app). There are details about [workbox-webpack plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin). It will take care of generating a service worker file that will automatically precache all of your local assets and keep them up to date as you deploy updates.

Answer (score 1):

this means your resources are not getting cached properly,
you need to add them to cache before accessing,
workbox by default do it for you.
it shows 2 files cached, as they present in your array, expected result
same do it for all remaining too.

```
const staticAssets = [
    "./",
    "./images/favicon.png",
    "./js/app.min.js",
    "./manifest.json",
    { url: '/index.html', revision: '383676' }
]
```

you can try to add eventlistener,

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('Attempting to install service worker and cache static assets');
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open("staticCacheName")
    .then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(staticAssets);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request)
  .then(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: how? i thought doing `workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(staticAssets);` should cache it.